# Error in checking for if mouse is in tolerance

Tags: if-statement, processing, collision

I have a rect, which I want to disappear when it's getting clicked.

I use the following method to control if the mouseX and height*0.9 is in the area of the rectangle when clicked:

```
//balken is a ArrayList of the object holding the variables for the rectangle
boolean mouseInTolerance()
{
  return ((mouseX > balken.get(0).x- balken.get (0).balkenWidth*.5
      || mouseX < balken.get(0).x+ balken.get (0).balkenWidth*.5)
      && (height*.9 > balken.get(0).y- tolerance
      || height*.9 <balken.get(0).y+ tolerance));
```

However, this returns true no matter where the mouse has been clicked.

***Edit***: rectMode is set to CENTER

Comment: It's processing (i wrote it int the tags). Processing is a java extension optimised for grafical programming.

Comment: What is the value of balken.get(0)? Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead? Feel free to hard-code the values to keep it as short as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider this line:

```
 return ((mouseX > balken.get(0).x- balken.get (0).balkenWidth*.5
      || mouseX < balken.get(0).x+ balken.get (0).balkenWidth*.5)
      && (height*.9 > balken.get(0).y- tolerance
      || height*.9 <balken.get(0).y+ tolerance));
```

Now let's substitute in a value for your variables, just to more easily see what's going on. It doesn't really matter what values we choose, so let's go with these:

```
balken.get(0).x = 100;
balken.get(0).y = 200;
balken.get(0).balkenWidth = 20;
balken.get(0).balkenHeight = 30;
height = 1000;
tolerance = 10;
```

Doing the substitution, you get this:

```
 return (mouseX > 90 || mouseX < 110)
     && (900 > 190 || 900 < 210);
```

Now let's take each half of that:

```
(mouseX > 90 || mouseX < 110)
```

When will that ever be false? Can you come up with a number for mouseX that makes this false? It looks like you were trying to determine when mouseX was between these two points, right? Therefore, you want **and** between these two inequalities, not or.

Similarly:

```
(900 > 190 || 900 < 210)
```

You can change that 900 to any value, and this will never be false. Again, you want an **and** operator in there, not an or.

The reason for this is simple. Let's say we have three X values: LEFT, MIDDLE, and RIGHT. How do we determine when the MIDDLE point is between the LEFT point and the RIGHT point? The MIDDLE point has to be to the right of the LEFT point- in other words, MIDDLE > LEFT. It **also** has to be to the left of the RIGHT point- in other words, MIDDLE > LEFT && MIDDLE < RIGHT.

The same logic applies to the vertical y value.

Comment: Thanks, I totaly didn't think about that both this.